# change the python I used in spyder

Tags: python, pip, path, spyder

I tried to  `!pip install`  library in my pc, but it kept showing error, so I download python 3.10.1 and I successfully install the library I want, but now I still can't import the library but the library has already been installed, how can I change the path of python in spyder?

Comment: Install the libraries for python 3.10.1.

Comment: Maybe this wiki page could be useful for you: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder